# Replace text within specific part of NSString

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Is it possible to change text within a specific part of an NSString? For example, I want to use `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString`, but only within a certain part of a string. In this example, I only want to replace `#`'s after `#q=`, and before `&lang=en-us`. Like this:

Initial string: `https://google.com/search#q=hello#&lang=en-us`

What it should be replaced with: `https://google.com/search#q=hello%23&lang=en-us`

What using `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` returns if I tell it to replace `#`'s with `%23`: `https://google.com/search%23q=hello%23&lang=en-us`

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is Q&A communitiy that works that provides free answer. You could pay back to the community by selecting correct answer that solves your problem and upvoting answer that guided in the right direction. This also improves your chances of getting answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The direct answer to your question is yes, you can use `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:`; the `range` parameter specifies the part of the string within which replacements should be done.

There are other searching methods provide by `NSString` which may help you determine a suitable value for `range`.

Having said the above your approach is probably rather "fragile" - prone to break easily as input data changes - and maybe you should consider the string as what it is, a URL, and either construct it with appropriate escaping in the first place; or parse it into its parts, add the escaping, and then reassemble. There are methods on  `NSURL` and `NSString` which help you do that.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to URL encode existing string

```
NSString *input = @"https://google.com/search#q=hello%23&lang=en-us";
NSURL *url = @"https://google.com/search#q=hello%23&lang=en-us";
NSString *params = [url parameterString];
NSString *enc = [params stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:
 NSUTF8StringEncoding];
//append URLs host+path with enc
```

No error checking is done in above code, it only gives idea

Comment: Thanks for your response! The problem with this solution is that using this outputs the string with the hashtags and percent signs changed to the correct UTF8 encoding, but it does it for the entire string, not just within the `#q=` part.